# Use Angular service to login using cypress

Tags: angular, cypress

I am using cypress to test our Angular application. After reading a lot on cypress' best practices I now would like to refactor our custom cypress login command. Currently it uses the UI for logging in.

I found the example on how to login using application code (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/logging-in__using-app-code) but with this I am running into troubles with our Angular app. Obviously we are using an Angular service to handle the login. Now trying to replicate the code from the example does not work using an Angular service:

```
// test.spec
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/core/http/auth.service'

describe('Landing Page Test', () => {
  it('should log the user in running app code', () => {
    // I cannot run it like this, coz service is a class
    AuthService.login('username','password');

    // I also cannot instantiate the AuthService because it has injected dependencies
    // so this does not compile:
    const authService = new AuthService();
  });
});

// AuthService (shortend ...)
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private apiHttpService: ApiHttpService) {}

  login(username, password) {
    // do login stuff
  }
}
```

Is there any way to tap into that service and run the login from there? Or is this not possible with Angular?

Answer (score 2):

Oh I found the answer but it seems pretty hacky, you add the following to your service:

```js
constructor() {
    if (window['Cypress']) window['AuthService'] = this
}

myFunctionName() {
    console.log("Oh I hope I'll get called from Cypress!")
}
```

And in Cypress you'll be able to do this:

```js
it.only('Dev', () => {
    cy.window().then((w) => {
        w.AuthService.myFunctionName()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a hacky method for this, that you can get ngContext from an element. For example the root element is app-root, then you can do like this

```
const e = document.getElementsByTagName('app-root')[0];
console.log(e.__ngContext__);
const appComponent = e.__ngContext__[8].components[0];
console.log(appComponent);
```

Then you can get all the injected services in appComponent.

[Example from angular doc site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0CSQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

A service is just a property of the component it is used in. And I believe the root that the service is provided in is just your app.component.ts. You should be able to do something like this

```
  let angular: any;

  cy
    .window()
    .then(win => angular = (win as any).ng)
    .then(() => cy.document())
    .then(doc => {
      const appComponent = angular.getComponent(appComponentSelector);
      appComponent.apiHttpService.myFunctionName()
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Please note that the following will *not* answer your question (of how to call a Angular service function. It does however answer how to make a super fast login method for your Cypress routes.

---

I add the command `cy.login()` that logs in with a default user. Fake credentials are stored in `cypress.json`. After logging in store the JWT token in `fixtures/login-data.json`. Next time `cy.login` is called first check if there's still a valid token present, if so use that one.

*Before you can start using this you'll need to create `cypress/fixtures/login-data.json` which contains an object `{}`.*

```js
const loginSet = (field, data) =>
    localStorage.setItem(
        field,
        JSON.stringify({
            token: data.token,
            user: data.user,
            company: data.user.companyRef.company,
        })
    )

const loginClear = (field) => localStorage.removeItem(field)

// Quick log in method without calling endpoint every restart
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {

    // Get variables
    const localStorageConfig = 'auth-2020-0'
    const user = Cypress.config('user')
    const email = user.email.value
    const password = user.security.password.value

    // Check if we have a JWT token in storage
    cy.fixture('login-data.json').then((dataStored) => {
        // Check if token in store is still valid
        const tokenExist = dataStored && dataStored.token
        const tokenValid = tokenExist && dataStored.token.expires > Date.now()

        // Token is valid! We do not need to log in again!
        // console.log({ dataStored, tokenExist, tokenValid })
        if (tokenValid) return loginSet(localStorageConfig.name, dataStored)

        // No token found, we log in again
        cy.request({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/public/auth/login',
            body: { email, password },
        }).then((httpResp) => {
            const data = httpResp.body.data
            cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/login-data.json', data)
            loginSet(localStorageConfig.name, data)
        })
    })
})

Cypress.Commands.add('logout', () => {
    const localStorageConfig = Cypress.config('localStorage')
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/login-data.json', {})
    loginClear(localStorageConfig.name)
})
```

Comment: nice solution for your use case. thanks for sharing. due to how our authentication is set up, it's not applicable for me though.

Comment: this is a nice solution, but is not related to the question the OP asked.

Comment: See my first sentence: "Please note that the following will not answer your question."

Comment: The point of stackoverflow is to give answers in context of the question.  You are more than welcome to ask a question that requires your answer and then answer it with your answer. But this most certainly does not belong here.  Nice solution, but not for this question.